# QVector2D* unknown size

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is about Qt compiler error: "QVector2D*: unknown size"

I've a Mesn class which holds some data for mesh definition like below.

```
class Mesh
{

public:

Mesh();
Mesh(const Mesh &other);
~Mesh();

private:

QVector<QVector3D> m_colors;
QVector<int> m_faces;
QVector<int> m_lines;
QVector<QVector3D> m_normals;
QVector<QVector2D> m_uvs;
QVector<QVector3D> m_vertices;
};
```

And in the cpp file I've this.

```
Mesh::Mesh()
{
m_colors   = QVector<QVector3D>();
m_faces    = QVector<int>();
m_lines    = QVector<int>();
m_normals  = QVector<QVector3D>();
m_uvs      = QVector<QVector2D>();
m_vertices = QVector<QVector3D>();
}

Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh &other)
{
m_colors   = other.GetColors();
m_faces    = other.GetFaces();
m_lines    = other.GetLines();
m_normals  = other.GetNormals();
m_uvs      = other.GetUVs();
m_vertices = other.GetVertices();
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{

}
```

But I'm getting a compiler error I've mentioned about for only m_uvs. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You need an `#include` file with a definition of `QVector2D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your default constructor is not needed. The members will be default-constructed by the compiler-generated default constructor. Even if you had your own constructor, you don't need to default construct any non-POD members at all. POD members are plain old data types like `int` or `bool[5]`. Anything that is a class or a struct will be default constructed for you, so no need to do it explicitly.
2. The copy constructor is not needed. The compiler will generate one for you. Same goes for the assignment operator and the destructor. That's the benefit of using properly designed C++ classes. You just use them, the compiler does all the boilerplate code generation for you.
3. If you provide *any* of the [big three](http://cerebro.xu.edu/csci175/notes97m/bigthree.html): the destructor, the copy constructor, the assignment operator, you *must* provide all of them. When using C++11, the big three becomes the big four with addition of the move constructor.
4. If you don't want the class to be copyable (you have a non-default destructor but you don't want to write the copy/move constructors nor the assignment operator), there's a Qt-provided macro for that:

   ```
   class MyClass {
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyClass)  // no semicolon!
     ...
   };
   ```
5. You forgot to `#include <QVector2D>` in your .cpp file.

Incidentally, your code reads like Delphi/Borland Pascal code, where the compiler was of little help, compared to C++. In C++, if you use properly designed C++ classes as members of your class, you won't need to manually generate neither copy constructor nor the assignment operator, nor a destructor.

Essentially, your `Mesh` class can look as follows:

```
// header

class Mesh
{
  QVector<QVector3D> m_colors;
  QVector<int> m_faces;
  QVector<int> m_lines;
  QVector<QVector3D> m_normals;
  QVector<QVector2D> m_uvs;
  QVector<QVector3D> m_vertices;
public:
  Mesh();
  // You always need a const getter. The non-const getter is optional
  // if you allow modification of the member.
  QVector<QVector3D> & colors() { return m_colors; }
  const QVector<QVector3D> & colors() const { return m_colors; }
  // etc.
};

// implementation

Mesh::Mesh()
{}

// example

void test() {
  Mesh m;
  QVector<QVector3D> myColors;
  m.colors() = myColors; // works like a setter
  const Mesh cm;
  cm.colors() = myColors; // won't compile since cm is const
  QVector<QVector3D> colors = cm.colors(); // assigns to a local copy that can be changed
  colors << QVector3D(...);
}
```

Comment: Yes including QVector2D is solved my problem. I am forgetting this frequently. What is a move constructor by the way, I'll search it. I am doing data member access methods like this. "inline QVector<QVector3D>    GetColors()   const { return m_colors; }"

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü Your `Get` methods return copies of the data, that's an unnecessary overhead. You should return a reference instead. In Qt style, the reference-returning getter doesn't have a `get` prefix, since you can use it to both *get* and *set* the value.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü If you want a copy of the data, you can explicitly assign from the reference returned by the getter to a local variable. I've edited the example code to demonstrate this.

Comment: I've created my classes as you sad. By the way can I use header file for the implementation of empty default constructor?

Comment: I mean this "class A { public: A() {}};" Is it wrong for specially for compiler generated constructors?

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü It depends on whether everything needed for the compiler to generate such code is available in the header. Sometimes one wants to forward-declare some classes and only include their full declarations in the implementation file. In any case, the compiler will let you know in no uncertain terms when the implementation cannot be present in the header file :)